# Origin of .testWriteFolder on my computer?

Tags: virus, troubleshooting, crashplan

I logged onto my computer today and there were 2 mysterious folders on my desktop. They both begin with **.testWriteFolder** followed by an 18 digit number beginning with 804. Both folders are empty. I searched online for support/help, and the best I could find was a [twitter conversation](https://twitter.com/crashplan/status/237598634378682368?lang=en) mentioning these folders and linking them to CrashPlan.

**Anybody know what these are??**

---

The twitter post:

[image]

---

Note: I'm using Windows 7 (64-bit) and have CrashPlan version 4.8.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It *is* CrashPlan related.**

- These folders are created to test the write capabilities of CrashPlan and are normally auto deleted. However, sometimes they are not properly removed.

---

I talked to a CrashPlan support agent today.

At first he said the folders had nothing to do with CrashPlan, but after I sent him a link to the [twitter comment](https://twitter.com/crashplan/status/237598634378682368?lang=en) posted in the question, he said this:

> Thanks for your patience. After speaking with several colleagues on the support, I reached out to an engineer to get some additional details. As it turns out, **that file IS related to CrashPlan**. I sincerely apologize for inaccurately stating that was not the case.
>
> In short, this **occurs as part of a test process CrashPlan does to confirm it has read and write access on the computer**. **CrashPlan generally cleans up this file after the test is complete, but in some instances it is left behind**. After more recent releases of the CrashPlan app, this behavior is far less common, but still possible.
>
> I just confirmed you are **safe to delete the file** and it should no longer appear again unless a reinstall is necessary.

He then added some more specifics:

> To provide a little bit of background, the CrashPlan app needs read and write access on the drive in order for the backup to run. **To test that it has write access on the computer, CrashPlan creates that file, which it is eventually supposed to “clean up” once the test is complete**. Sometimes it can be blocked from cleaning it up, which will result in it being left behind.

He followed up with:

> I’d say, continue monitoring if it gets re-created for the time being. It may be indicative of a larger permissions issue with the CrashPlan app.
>
> If it doesn’t appear again, I wouldn’t be concerned based on what I was told about the folder. **It’s existence isn’t a problem. It just means CrashPlan couldn’t clean up after going through a basic process**.

Finally, he had this to say about any potential security issues:

> **Absolutely not a security issue**. If anything, there is a permissions issue where CrashPlan doesn’t have access to remove the file.